# Setting value to datetime-local HTML input

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I have an HTML input object of `type="datetime-local"` to which I would like to set a custom value which is `now()` + 3 hours everytime its value is changed.

Basing on the fact that `alert(object.value)` returns a string of type `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM`, I've thought I would need (apart for calculating the date) also to format the string properly. So I have:

### Added the onchange attribute to the HTML

```
<input .... onchange="datesReactions()"/>
```

### Extended the JS Date prototype to add the hours

```
Date.prototype.addHours = function(h) {
   this.setTime(this.getTime() + (h*60*60*1000)); 
   return this;   
}
```

### Created the datesReactions() function as follows

```
function datesReaction(){
    var adesso = new Date;
    document.getElementById('ExecutionDate').value = parseDateToInput(adesso.addHours(3));
}
```

where the parsing to string is performed by the following simple function:

```
function parseDateToInput(jsDate){

    var jsDay = jsDate.getDate();
    if (jsDay < 10){jsDay = '0' + jsDay;}
    var jsMonth = jsDate.getMonth();
    if (jsMonth < 10){jsMonth = '0' + jsMonth;}
    var jsYear = jsDate.getFullYear();
    if (jsYear < 10){jsYear = '0' + jsYear;}
    var jsHour = jsDate.getHours();
    if (jsHour < 10){jsHour = '0' + jsHour;}
    var jsMinute = jsDate.getMinutes();
    if (jsMinute < 10){jsMinute = '0' + jsMinute;}

    return jsYear + '-' + jsMonth + '-' + jsDay + 'T' + jsHour + ':' + jsMinute;
}
```

However, although the single pieces of code work themselves, the above does nothing when I change the value of my input. 
Could anyone please help me understanding what I do wrong? I have prepared the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p59jmrjg/4/) in order to help you helping a beginner debugging :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: there is not change event yet for datetime-local. You can add only a `onblur` event

Comment: why is it editable if it can only be set to 3 hours from now() ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v78cgujk/